# Remove php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I got this website under development and need to remove .php extension from my urls. Trying to make the urls shorter and without the ending extension.

In my root i have files in this format:
    www.domain.com/index.php
    www.domain.com/about.php
    www.domain.com/services.php

..and other similar pages, with no subfolders

Tried this code with no effect

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you can, I would recommend using a popular PHP framework to increase development time and get what you're looking for.  I've recently used Laravel 4 and it's pretty nice.  But Silverstripe, CakePHP, Zend, Yii, Symfony, Phalcon, CodeIgniter (although this one was dropped by the developer) and Kohana are popular choices.  Of course, there's also CMS's but I'll assume you're looking for to custom build stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to catch the regex group `$1`

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks jay, its working now

i have no experience with any php framework but looking into that since i'm used to doing php-based websites that dont need a cms backend